# How to manually refresh xbox music song library/index list in windows phone

Tags: music, 8.1-update-1, lumia-denim-update

My default music player stops playing songs at the ending of a song even after i selected a playlist of more than 1 songs. Because of this I am unable to play any songs for long time. I tried installing other free music player app from store but most of them were just clones of default music player. Do you have any suggestions for a music player?

EDITED

I have edited the title because i have found out the reason why  my Xbox music is not playing songs. I have saved all of my songs(mp3) in my SD card and a while back i have deleted some of the songs from SD card using data cable. Even after deleting the songs from SD card the xbox music app kept the indexes of those deleted songs. While playing songs these indexes (deleted songs) interfere and doesn't allow to play further. Any one has any idea how to refersh the song library/index list in xbox music app.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that if you choose a playlist of more than one song, music will stop after the first song? Are the songs stored on your device or streamed from Xbox Music? If on your device, do they have any DRM protection (e.g. from Xbox Music Pass)?

Comment: @Indrek I store all my songs in my SD card (no streaming). most of the songs were downloaded from youtube, sound cloud in mp3 format. The problem started after denim upgradation

Comment: Did you try a back-up, and hard reset of your phone?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I didn't tried both. As i mentioned in my question the problem is not with the phone but with the xbox music app. I am currently using quickplay app and i am able to manually refresh music index and it also works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is late, but as of September 2015, this problem persists.

So here is what i use as a fix.

Connect the phone to the PC and browse to the folder where you have music that doesnt show up in the WP music app. Create a new folder at this location (keep it empty, you just have to create a new folder) on the PC, and then go up one folder. At this point the music app scans the paths again and now "finds" music that was earlier not indexed. I have tried this several times and have had 100% success rate.

You dont have to go to every folder where the music has not been discovered. Often, you just need to create one new directory to trigger the indexing and all other missing music is indexed.

Once all music has been "discovered" delete the empty directory you had created.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: + 1 This worked for me in updating the files after adding them to the library.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question, but I stumble upon the same issue and the below steps addressed the bug/ shortcoming in Xbox music app.

On a Windows Phone 8.1 perform the below steps

1. In Batter Saver, locate Music and tap on it.
2. Ensure Both 'Allow app to run in the background' is On and 'Allow
   this app to run in the background even when Battery Saver' is ticked.
3. Reboot the phone.
4. Charge the phone a while before opening Xbox music

Source: [Windows central](http://forums.windowscentral.com/groove-music/325467-xbox-music-not-reflecting-music-library-change.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am writing answer to my own question so any one facing similar problem can also find solution here.Because of my problem with Xbox music app; i started searching for an alternative music app. With a bit of luck i came across this app [Quickplay](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quickplay/30344f10-3fe4-4b07-85aa-f3061c98215e), by far the app plays 
songs with out any glitch, the only problem is the advertisment and a paid folder navigation. The XBOX music app still have the problem with refreshing music index list which i think Microsoft will solve in there next update.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just see the repeat icon [image: Repeat] to the right of the Album art.

There are 3 variants of Repeat:

1. Repeat All: [image: Repeat]
2. Repeat One: [image: Repeat one]
3. Repeat None: (Faded Repeat Icon)

Please check if the repeat icon is set to repeat all or repeat one.

[image: Xbox Music]

Comment: The problem started after denim upradation. i believe this caused some kind of bug or glich in my music app. Any way it is still not working i will wait for next xbox music app update.